# Avoid timeout on long running process of report generation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, timeout

I have a webapp developed using Spring MVC. I am using jasperReports to generate a series of reports for the user to download. In several of these reports, filling them by jasper takes too long and this causes either a transaction timeout, a Tomcat Timeout or a gateway timeout on the client side.

What's a good solution for long-running processes like this? Note that it should somehow inform the user whenever the process is finished so he can download the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest way to handle such issue is to have an asyncronous communication with your client.

The first request `/myApp/report?name=...&paramters...` triggers jasper report to refresh the report and returns a ticket id

Then, the client have to call another url to retrieve the report (for instance every 5 seconds) `/myApp/reportDownload?ticketId=xxxxx`

If the jasper thread is over and the report ready, you send back the report, otherwise tell the client to retry in 5 seconds until it gets the report.

The way to implement it depends on the technlogies you are using in for the front and backends, but you'll find dozen of tutorials on the internet.

The worst way to fix it is to increase the timeout in the connector configuration (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

HIH

Comment: That implies storing the report in a temp file, doesn't it? I am currently writing the byte stream directly on the response. I guess that solution is not valid anymore.

Comment: yes, the thread that triggers jasper will store the ticket id with the flag "pending", write the response in a temp file, and then reset the flag has terminated (in a ConcurrentHashMap for instance). then the requests on reportDownload read this map and when the ticket is marked as done, read the file from the disk and write it on the response